# Creating module with pybind11 and debugging it in Python at runtime crash

Tags: boost-python, pybind11

I'm re-posting my issue from https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/discussions/4477 to here as I'm not getting much luck there for now...

To summarize I have C++ application that has Python in it via Boost. I want to load a C++ DLL in to it via pybind11 and debug my DLLs at runtime via attaching myself to the process and breakpoints in the source.

Sadly when I hit breakpoint I get that crazy error that you can see there.

I think this is the relevant part:

```
00007FFAE47AEAA5 (ucrtbased): (filename not available): get_wide_winmain_command_line
00007FFAE47AE8C3 (ucrtbased): (filename not available): get_wide_winmain_command_line
00007FFAE47B158F (ucrtbased): (filename not available): wassert
00007FFACC14B3F0 (python37_d): (filename not available): PyAST_Validate
S:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pybind11\detail\internals.h (414): `pybind11::detail::get_internals'::`2'::gil_scoped_acquire_local::gil_scoped_acquire_local
S:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pybind11\detail\internals.h (417): pybind11::detail::get_internals
S:\RnD\DLL_python\c_DLL_Python_01\icLib\library.cpp (34): PyInit_mydll
```

I've tried setting up compiler flags/etc but sadly no luck.

Is it possible to compile pybind11 to pyd DLL on Windows & load it in Python and then breakpoint into it?

To anyone wondering why I'm jumping over so many hoops and not using Python... I wrote a framework in C++ that works between 4 apps via C++ API, sadly 5th app is only Python and thus I "can" use my framework via pybind11 but I need help debugging.